# Как получить разницу между цветами в процентах в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio

Задача состоит в том, чтобы получить конкретный стандартизованный цвет (он будет с 100% желаемой чистотой) путем смешивания различных предложенных цветов. Я мог бы сравнить их параметры RGB и посмотреть, соответствует ли смесь эталону (true/false). Однако условие состоит в том, что могут быть разные оттенки желаемого цвета. Некоторые из этих оттенков близки к эталонным (где-то на 90% или 80% похожи), а некоторые нет (60% и ниже). Таким образом, если цвет имеет по крайней мере 80% сходства, вы выигрываете, ниже этого значения - вы проигрываете. Я просто не могу понять, как сделать эту проверку цвета в процентах.

**Пример:**

Есть массив с множеством возможных цветов для смешивания:

```
Color[] aColors = { new Color(1f, 1f, 0f), new Color(0.3f, 0.9f, 0f),
                   new Color(1f, 0.6f, 0f), new Color(1f, 0f, 0f),
                   new Color(0.5f,0f,0f), new Color(0.5f, 0f, 0.9f),
                   new Color(0f, 0.3f, 0f)};
```

Эталонный цвет - лаймовый:

```
Color(0.43f,0.74f,0f)
```

Правильный выбор смеси из массива следующий (смешение желтого и зеленого):

```
resutColor = aColors[0] + aColors[1]/ 2
```

При смешивании оттенка темно-красного с зеленым также получается несколько салатовый цвет, и это следует учитывать, указывая, насколько результат близок к эталонному оттенку в процентах.

Темно-красный цвет:

```
new Color(0.5f,0f,0f)
```

Comment: [Color difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)?

Comment: Вероятно, цвет нужно перевести в [HSV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_(цветовая_модель)) или HSL и сравнивать тон(?).

Comment: Самое основное - решить, в чем именно измерять сходство, а вычисление уже дело техники. В зависимости от того, как считать сходство, один и тот же цвет быть похожим и не похожим на эталонный.

Comment: У меня всего один вопрос, если полное совпадение значений цветов это 100% то, что такое 0%? Пример? Вот чего ты не можешь понять. Цвет это не то что можно посчитать в процентах. Какую бы систему ты не выбрал, считать разницу `rgb`, как `xyz` в диапазоне `0-1.732051` (`1, 1, 1` максимум), среднее арифметическое разниц `rgb`, среднее арифметическое разниц `hsv` где `h` считается как окружность, твой результат скорее всего будет колыпаться в районе 50-100%. Каждый вариант будет иметь свой изъян. Цвета это не отрезок, это скорее `rgb` куб либо треугольная призма или `hsv` цилиндр.